# Preload images for jQuery Supersized?

Tags: preload, image-preloader, supersized

is it possible to preload images for the supersized plugin (http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)?
I put the images in an invisible container at the top of the HTML document, but it doesn't seem to have any effect. A specific image is only loaded when I click next/prev Slide.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
Tina